# Azure web app multi container (MEAN app), what is the URL to connect to node backend container from front end container?

Tags: node.js, angular, docker, azure-web-app-service, mean-stack

Trying to learn to deploy angular app to azure web app using multi-container, the frontend loads fine but cant connect to the backend node container, I want to add the url of the node backend to my angular frontend but i cant figure out what it is. I've tried https://rojesh.azure.io:3000, https://rojesh.azurewebsites.net:3000, http://server:3000 and more but nothing seems to work. Website Hostname: https://rojesh.azurewebsites.net and the acr name is rojesh.azurecr.io which has 3 images. This is my config file for compose in azure:

```
version: '3.3'

services:
    db:
      image: rojesh.azurecr.io/db:latest
      ports:
        - "27017:27017"
      restart: always
      networks:
        - app-network

    server:
      image: rojesh.azurecr.io/server:latest
      depends_on:
        - db
      ports:
        - "3000:3000"
      restart: always
      networks:
        - app-network

    app:
      depends_on:
        - server
      image: rojesh.azurecr.io/app:latest
      environment:
        NGINX_HOST: rojesh.azurewebsites.net
        NGINX_PORT: 80
      ports:
        - "80:80"
      restart: always
      networks:
        - app-network

networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge
```

The app works fine locally using docker compose which is:

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  docker-app:
    build:
      context: app 
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    ports:
      - '4200:4200'
    volumes:
      - ./app/src:/app/src 
      

  docker-server:
    build:
      context: server
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment: 
      PORT: 3000
      MONGODB_URI: mongodb://mongo:27017/rojesh
      JWT_SECRET: secret
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    depends_on: 
      - mongo
    volumes:
      - ./server:/server

  mongo:
    container_name: mongo-server
    image: mongo:latest
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @ [ajkuma-msft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/users/ajkuma-msft/). Azure App Service only exposes ports `80` and `443`. Yes, incoming requests from client would just be over `443/80` which should be mapped to the **exposed port of the container**.
App Service will attempt to detect which port to bind to your container. If you want to bind to your container the **WEBSITES_PORT** app setting and configure it with a value of the port.

Web App for Containers currently allows you to expose **only one port** to the outside world. The container can only listen for HTTP requests on a single port.

From Docker compose configuration stand-point : Ports other than `80` and `8080` are ignored.

Refer [Docker Compose options](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/app-service/configure-custom-container?pivots=container-linux#configure-multi-container-apps)  lists shows **supported** and **unsupported** Docker Compose configuration options.

Refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/447302/access-multiple-ports-in-docker-compose-azure-web.html)